# Does $arg \left(\dfrac {z-1}{z+1}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ represent a circle or arc of a circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Does $arg \left(\dfrac {z-1}{z+1}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ represent a circle or arc of a circle?

By substituting $x+iy=z$ I do get equation of a circle. But I feel it should be one particular arc of the circle (the locus) depending on the direction of rotation of $(z-1)$ to $(z+1)$ by Coni's method.

Can someone clarify this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$z=x+iy\implies\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=\dfrac{(x-1+iy)(x+1-iy)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}=\dfrac{x^2+y^2-1+i(2y)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), arg$\dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2-1}=\dfrac\pi3$ if $x^2+y^2-1>0$

In that case, $x^2+y^2-1=2\sqrt3y\iff x^2+(y-\sqrt3)^2=2^2$

WLOG any point on $x^2+(y-\sqrt3)^2=2^2$ can be represented as $2\cos t,\sqrt3+2\sin t$

Now $x^2+y^2-1=\cdots=6+4\sqrt3\sin t$ which will be $>0\iff\sin t>-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2$

So, its not the full circle, but an arc is represented by arg$\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=\dfrac\pi3$

Comment: Hey could you explain that atan2 function you linked.I read it but it's going over my head :-P.And could you explain how to choose which arc of circle it will be ?You did not mention that in your answer..

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, Updated answer. Please pinpoint the confusion

Comment: Shouldn't it be $6 + 4\sqrt{3}\sin t$ instead of $7 + 4 \sqrt{3} \sin t$?

Comment: @DanShved, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 1):

Observe that (taking principal value of argument)

$$\arctan\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2-1}=\frac\pi3\iff\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2-1}=\tan\frac\pi3=\sqrt3\iff$$

$$\iff x^2+y^2-\frac2{\sqrt3}y-1=0\iff x^2+\left(y-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2=\frac43\;\;(**)$$

Which is a circle of radius $\;\frac2{\sqrt3}\;$ and center $\;\left(0,\,\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\;$

*Yet* the first equality means both denominator and numerator in the left side have the same sign. and thus

$$\begin{cases}y>0\;\text{and}\;x^2+y^2>1\,,\;\;\text{or}\\{}\\y<0\;\text{and}\;x^2+y^2<1\end{cases}$$

and thus the options are, in both cases, an arc of the circle $\;(**)\;$...though the cases are not symmetric.